# How to deploy spring boot application jar in heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku

I have used the below command to deploy executable jar for spring boot application(working in local mcahine)

```
heroku deploy:jar <jar file path> --app appName
```

It is shows deployed successfully but not running.But The same app is running fine while push the code to heroku git.Please suggest a way to solve this issue

Comment: Can you share your gradle/maven file?

Comment: What does `heroku logs` show after a deploy?

Comment: Try whit this... http://frugalisminds.com/spring-boot/deploy-spring-boot-app-on-heroku/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [proc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) file to deploy spring boot application in Heroku.

Create a file name Procfile in your app directory. 
Add the following line in it.

```
web: java -jar target/java-getting-started-1.0.jar
```

Redeploy the application.

For step by step instructions follow this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#define-a-procfile.

Comment: To determine the best `Procfile` entry, check `heroku ps` after deploying with Git.